# size difference in an image after downscale/upscale operation using imresize

Tags: matlab, image-resizing, mean-square-error

I resized an image with scale of 0.25 then upscaled it using scale of 4.

```
imageReduced = imresize(imageOriginal, 0.25, 'nearest');
imageGenerated = imresize(imageReduced, 4, 'nearest');
```

I want to calculate mean square error between `imageOriginal` and `imageGenerated` so they must have same height x width values. But after downscale and upscale operations image size  changes slightly because of the division.

For example;

size of `imageOriginal`  is 4811 x 6449 and 
size of `imageGenerated` is 4812 x 6452

How can I make downscale and upscale operations to make `imageGenerated` same size with `imageOriginal` to calculate mean square error between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imresize` support resize with fixed number of cols and rows: `imresize(img, [rows, cols])`. You can use this function variant for second resize.

```
imageReduced = imresize(imageOriginal, 0.25, 'nearest');
imageGenerated = imresize(imageReduced, size(imageOriginal), 'nearest');
```